# Validate multiple DropDownList yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I'm trying validate a multiple dropdownlist, like this:

[image: example error]

**view/form:**

```
<?=
$form->field($hours, 'hours_id', ['template' => '{label}{input}<span class="help-block">{hint}{error}</span>'])->dropDownList(Hours::getHierarchy(), ['size' => 10, 'multiple' => 'multiple'], ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', '-- Select --'),
])
?>
```

**model rules:**

```
['hours_id', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
```

**Result:**

> Hour is invalid.

Someone knows what's wrong? I tried to custom validation, and i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model rule like this

```
 [['hours_id'], 'each','integer'],
```

Answer (score 0):

By default multi select drop down for a field `name` will send options in following format:

```
name=value1&name=value2
```

To be able to receive data as array (as it suspected for `each` validation) You should use `name[]` instead of `name`.

For your case

```
<?=
    $form->field($hours, 'hours_id[]', ['template' => '{label}{input}<span class="help-block">{hint}{error}</span>'])->dropDownList(Hours::getHierarchy(), ['size' => 10, 'multiple' => 'multiple'], ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', '-- Select --')])
?>
```